# Are there any ways to calculate the subtraction of values from one 2-dimensional arrays in python?

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am finding a way to calculate the difference of values from one 2-dimensional array.

```
arr1 = [[1,2,3],[5,6,7]]
```

My array will be like this and I want my code to subtract 5-1,6-2 and 7-3.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: "Is it possible to do that?" -- Yes. Why don't you try and see what happens?

Comment: Thanks. I was trying and I was out of idea to solve. If this question somehow offends you ,it's my apologies.

Comment: It would have been a better question if you detailed your efforts and thereby allowed others to see where you were stuck. As it is, this reads like a student wanting Stack Overflow to do their homework for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `zip()`.

```
>>> arr1 = [[1,2,3], [5,6,7]]
>>> [b - a for (a, b) in zip(*arr1)]
[4, 4, 4]
```

(`zip(*x)` is an useful idiom in general to transpose an iterable of iterables, i.e. turn `[[1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7]]` to `[[1, 5], [2, 6], [3, 7]]`.)

Comment: Much appreciates!

Answer (score 0):

The one liner below seems to work

```
arr1 = [[1,2,3],[5,6,7]]
arr = [x - arr1[0][idx] for idx,x in enumerate(arr1[1])]
print(arr)
```

ourput

```
[4, 4, 4]
```

Comment: ... Why not `zip()`?

Comment: @AKX - you are right .. `zip` is a more *classic* solution ..

Comment: It works. Thanks I appreciate that.